# AsyncTask - Accessing variable from doInBackground in different class

Tags: android

Basically I am wanting to get access to a variable that has been assigned in doInBackground in a different class but I am not sure how to do this here. Below is my relevant class structure. This is for an android application. Thanks.

```
public class CreateNewPlayers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

public String doInBackground(String... args) {


                String playerid = playerid1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: is this value a result of task or You want to return it in the middle of process?

Comment: This is result taken from a user input.

Comment: I don't understand what You are trying to do. You have stared an AsyncTask, in doInBackground You get value from user input and would like to access this value somewhere else?

Comment: Yes I want to use this string in another class.

Comment: but if this is user input why don't You access it directly in this other class instead of trying to get it from AsyncTask.

Comment: I have tried doing this but I doesn't work for me.

Comment: It sound like what You doing and what You trying to do is completely wrong. Edit Your questions with more details about what You try to achieve and post more code you wrote to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can get access to intrim data using publishProgress() and onProgressUpdate()

```
public class CreateNewPlayers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public SomeOtherClass soc = null;

@Override
public String doInBackground(String... args) {


                String playerid = playerid1.getText().toString();
                publishProgress(playerid);

@Override
public String onProgressUpdate(String... args) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(args);
    soc.setPlayerID(args[0]);
    soc.DoSomething();
}
```

**Edit**
more complete

```
public class SomeOtherClass {
    protected String thisPlayerID = null;

    public setPlayerID (String pid) {
        thisPlayerID = pid;
    }

    public DoSomthing () {
        // act on data
    }
}

public class mainActivity extend Activity {
    public CreateNewPlayers cnp = new CreateNewPlayers();
    public SomeOtherClass soc = new SomeOtherClass();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle data) {
        super.onCreate(data);
        cnp.soc = soc;
        cnp.exectue("")
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not quite sure how I should be using onProgressUpdate.

Comment: onProgressUpdate is called when you publishProgress. DoSomethingWithData can be replaced by whatever it is you need to do with your playerid variable